# Convert a Unicode time in a CSV spreadsheet so I can import to MySQL date/time stamp

Tags: mysql, excel, unix, csv, timestamp

I'm stuck on this. I have a guestbook I'm converting from an old website into Wordpress comments. The guestbook has all the dates written in as unix. I already have the file transposed so I can import it into Wordpress comments and all works good, except the date field, which defaults to 0000-00-00 00:00:00.

I also have fields in standard Excel time formats but I need to find a way to conver that to the standard 0000-00-00 00:00:00.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the "standard Excel time formats"?

Comment: It would help if we had a sample (screenshot/text) of how your data is in excel right now. Also, please make your question clearer... "which defaults to 0000-00-00 00:00:00...to conver that to the standard 0000-00-00 00:00:00". Excel defaults to the format you want to convert to?...

Answer (score 1):

I actually figured this out after posting. Here was the issue. I had a CSV file from a previous guestbook that contained comments. In that CSV file the date / timestamp was in UNIX code (i.e. seconds since 1/1/1970).

In Excel, I found a formula to convert that to a date Excel can read. However, that date, when opened as a CSV, doesn't show in the correct format for MySQL. It uses the Excel date format, which is some string of numbers, I"m assuming similar to Unix time - from a certain date.

What I did was use the excel formula TEXT(Value, YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS) to convert the excel date/time to a string in the correct format. Then the CSV file worked.